# merge tuples in Python if the have elements in common and concatenate all the different elements in their position

Tags: python, merge, tuples

I have a problem in Python merging some tuples with items in common. The point is that I'd like to have just one tuple, but also preserve the different items, possibly by concatenating them in the position they have.

I'm analyzing ~100k captions connected to videos and specifically looking for verbs in them.
I have a big list of tuples like this:

```
(verb, caption, video_id)
```

The point is that if in a caption there are more than one verb, in my list it is present more than one time:

```
list = [(verb1, caption, video_id), (verb2, caption, video_id), (verb3, caption, video_id)]
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
(verb1|verb2|verb3, caption, video_id)
```

(the `|` is not mandatory, I simply would like to have all the 3 verbs in the first position of the tuple)

I need this because I'm outputting this to a csv file to be manually checked and I would like to avoid checking the same `caption` and `video_id` multiple times.

Here is a more reliable example:

```
list = [
  ('look', 'Mario takes the bag, looks around and runs away.','video_id_001'),
  ('run',  'Mario takes the bag, looks around and runs away.','video_id_001'),
  ('take', 'Mario takes the bag, looks around and runs away.','video_id_001')
]
```

Comment: Could you show us us data?

Comment: What is `verb1|verb2|verb3` suppose to be? Can you be specific? Are tuples really necessary? It sounds like you should probably use a `dict`

Comment: @RI don't think I could share the data (not a public dataset) but as an example:

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. If you can't share the data, make up your own data-set that has the same relevant properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is your friend.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('verb1', 'caption', 'video_id'),
       ('verb2', 'caption', 'video_id'),
       ('verb3', 'caption', 'video_id')]

aggregator = defaultdict(list)

# first create a dictionary mapping (caption, video_id) -> verb
for i, j, k in lst:
    aggregator[(j, k)].append(i)

# then reverse dictionary
result = [tuple(('|'.join(v), k[0], k[1])) for k, v in aggregator.items()]

# [('verb1|verb2|verb3', 'caption', 'video_id')]
```

Comment: I know that it's probably a stupid error from a stupid newbie, but if I try your method I face this error message when I type defaultdict(mylistofcaptions): 
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None"

Comment: @ng_, sorry not sure about that error. My code definitely works if you either copy/paste it into Jupyter notebook, another IDE, or run via command prompt.

Comment: you're right, tried your example code and works, I don't know why with my list is not working properly... always that error... O_O

Comment: @ng_ the error message states that the argument to `defaultdict` must be a *callable*, not a `list` object. You pass it the `list` type constructor, which is a function (a callable), not an *instance* of list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in fact I was feeding the defaultdict with the name of my list... (what an Idiot I am!)

Comment: @jp_data_analysis you solved my 3-days-searching/trying/mistaking problem! it works perfectly in my workflow!!!!!! As we say in Italy, I'm going to make a statue of you! hehehe
Thank you very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something, but how about:

```
list = [('look', 'Mario takes the bag, looks around and run away.','video_id_001'),('run', 'Mario takes the bag, looks around and run away.','video_id_001'),('take', 'Mario takes the bag, looks around and run away.','video_id_001')]
caption = "Mario takes the bag, looks around and run away"
vid_id = "video_id_001"

verbs = set()
for tup in list:
    verbs.add(tup[0])
print(('|'.join(verbs), caption, vid_id))
```

Comment: it would work if caption and vid_id would be stable... the point is that I have more than 100k unique captions linked to unique videos, and I'm filtering only captions containing a verb from a verb list.

Comment: You might want to update the question to explain that - since the question and example aren't clear on that point.